# How do you save the lat and lon (Geolocation) to database to track users location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, html, geolocation

At the moment I am using this code to find the user.

http://html5demos.com/geo/

I would like to store the users geolocation throughout the users session to provide them with relevant information in the area.

This is a Rails 3 app using a SQL DB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't much to storing a geolocation.  Just store the lat and long you receive in the database as decimals or doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store as a string ("lat,lon") because you are not doing anything much. You just need to display it back on the map.

If you need to do a search which users are in a bounding box, you need to change your database to `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL` or use `Solr` to do the job.

Comment: It might be time to upgrade to PostgreSQL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store lat, lng in session, hope you dont have stored much more there in session other than user_id

from your home page you can send position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude to your rails app, using ajax.

url like /store_ge_location?lat=<position.coords.latitude>&lng=<position.coords.longitude>

rails app will store that in session

```
session[:lat] = params[:lat]
```

and for subsequent requests rails app will find it in session, no need to gather it from browser

However, if you do not have any other use case around geo-location, why dont you simply read users location every time from browser?

Comment: The first solution sounds like it would fit better with my UX flow. Getting the users location every time would force the user to allow the site to access their location.

Comment: it wont repeat asking user to allow, for the same host